# C# Countdown Accumulation Timer

Tags: c#, timer, countdown

I have an application where I will be displaying a timer.

A user will perform an event and should complete it in a certain amount of time.
I currently have a timer that shows their time ticking down, but what I want now is a total accumulated time.  So every time a new event starts, the time to complete the event is added to their accumulated time.  Then as they are performing the event, the time is ticking off the accumulated time.

This is what I have for the "current timer"

```
u.StartingTime = u.ChangeOverStandard;
u.CurrentChangeOverTime = u.StartingTime - (DateTime.Now - u.ChangeOverStart);
```

All of these fields are timespans.  This works perfect for their "current" timer

But I need a "total" timer that will either show a positive timespan value..if they are getting done before they are supposed to...or a negative timespan value if they are taking too long.

EDIT:

So I want to achieve this:

For example : for "event 1", user has 30 sec. to end. Then user has a "TotalTimespan" property = 30. This total is decreased with the event timer. Let's say he finishes in 24 sec. That means he's got 6 sec left in TotalTimespan. Then "event2" must be finished in 40 sec. So in the begining of event2, TotalTimespan = TotalTimespane(6) + 40. = 46. If user uses 60 seconds, then TotalTimespan = 46 -60 = -14.

The "timer" is not a timer, and can't be used as a timer.  It is running on a background worker which is doing several other calculations as well.  So I can't just take off the time one second at a time.

On each new event, I've tried

```
u.AccumulatedTime += u.ChangeOverStandard;
```

and then

```
u.AccumulatedTime -= u.StartingTime - (DateTime.Now - u.ChangeOverStart);
```

But obviously that isn't going to work because it is taking the total elapsed time from the accumulated time every round through my loop

```
DateTime.Now - u.ChangeOverStart
```

^^Will give me the elapsed time from the beginning of the event to now, so is this what I'm wanting?

```
u.AccumulatedTime -= DateTime.Now - u.ChangeOverStart;
```

Comment: I cant figure out how to get a total.  I know it has to be simple, just cant figure it out.  I need a Total..so each time I add my "standard" to the total and count down until the user is finished

Comment: Well, the problem is... what you wanna achieve. For example : for "event 1", user has 30 sec. to end. Then user has a "TotalTimespan" property = 30. This total is decreased with the event timer. Let's say he finishes in 24 sec. That means he's got 6 sec left in TotalTimespan. Then "event2" must be finished in 40 sec. So in the begining of event2, TotalTimespan = TotalTimespane(6) + 40.  = 46. If user uses 60 seconds, then TotalTimespan = 46 -60 = -14. Did I understand well ?

Comment: By the way, you could give a little bit more code, maybe...

Comment: Thats exactly right. I didn't want to post a lot of code because I know it will cause confusion..I will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

All you would need is a TimeSpan and two DateTime static (global) variables to track the time and do the calculations.  Here's an example using your described numbers:

```
        TimeSpan left = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);  //30 seconds allowed for task.
        DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //User perform action.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(24000); //24 sec wait.
        DateTime stop = DateTime.UtcNow;
        left = left - (stop - start);
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling((double)left.TotalSeconds));
        //Output was: 6
        left = left + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 40);  //40 seconds allowed for task.
        start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //User perform action.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000); //60 sec wait.
        stop = DateTime.UtcNow;
        left = left - (stop - start);
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling((double)left.TotalSeconds));
        //Output was: -14
        left = left + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);  //30 seconds allowed for task.
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling((double)left.TotalSeconds));
        //Output was: 16
```

As you can see, the remaining time in the end is 16 seconds as you would expect.

Comment: Cornelius, be sure to look at the DATES on questions.  You just "answered" a question from 2012.  The original author was last seen in 2017...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Surely we don't want to just NOT answer questions that are old, do we?  If that's the case, old, unanswered questions should rather be deleted.  Just because the asker may have found a workaround doesn't mean someone else would not benefit from a provided answer.